# Is it possible to recover a failed message from mail flow?

Tags: office365

Is it possible, and if so how, to recover a failed message from mail flow?

I am assuming this could be possible, though the functionally may not exist.

Basically there is a lot of emails that went to a address that was not setup yet. I can see the emails all sitting in Mail Flow when I do a message trace, just cannot workout how to retrieve/recover the messages.

Dale